# Find the discharge Q. Pipe flows

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Trying to work my way through an example in my course notes on fluid flow in pipes and I'm really stuck on where to start. The question is as follows;

A pipeline 10km long and 300mm diameter with a relative roughness of 0.03mm conveys water from a reservoir (water level 850 m above datum) to a treatment plant (700m above datum). Assume all head loss takes place in the pipe and hence find the discharge.

So I know I have to use either the Moody Diagram or the Colebrook-
White transition formula to do this. So I was going to make a guess at f and use iteration, but my iteration formula contains the Reynolds number and in order to work out the Re I need to know the value of the water velocity?

I'm just majorly over thinking the whole problem and confusing myself. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Relative roughness does not have any units, since it is relative to the diameter and what iteration formula did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Either the flow would be laminar, in which case $f$ would be inversely proportional to the Reynolds number, in which case you can solve for the velocity analytically. Or the flow would be turbulent (since these exercises will normally not use the transition area), in which case $f$ would [asymptotically approach a constant value](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/moody-diagram-d_618.html) when the Reynolds number increases, thus you could approximate this by saying that $f$ would not be a function of the Reynolds number as first iteration.